# How do I modify the <head> tags in a Joomla website?

Tags: html, joomla, meta

My website was created in joomla 1.5. I want to edit my website pages header tags. Specifically the `<head>` area. How can I do that?

Comment: In the future, questions about Joomla would be better asked at [joomla.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the `<head>` tags yourself in your template and can add any content you wish between those tags. In most CMS's you have complete control in what appears between the head tags. With Joomla you are required to add `<jdoc:include type="head" />` however. The content of that tag is automatically filled by Joomla such as meta data (title, description, etc.).

You can edit the global meta data in the control panel Site > Global Configuration. Also on each article you create you can click on the side menu to edit the meta data for that particular article.

However, there are some things you cannot easily change. Such as in that joomla tag `<jdoc:include type="head" />` it also loads MooTools for instance. Which means if you wish to load Mootools at the foot of the page your out of luck. You could manually edit the tag in /libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php however whatever changes you make there may be overwritten every time you update the system. So you do not want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the head section you need to access to the admin dashboard. Inside Extensions/Themes, then into themes select your default theme. Go into the editor select the file /html/com_content/default.php and you could modified the file as you want.

At the same place you could find the file index.php that has the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla (even version 3.6.x) doesn't provide any mechanism to do this via the admin UI. There are a few different lower-level options (see https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) but non-developers may find it hard to use.

There are some Joomla templates that allow you to specify global custom code to be placed at the end of header and/or end of body sections (for example for Google Analytics). I'm using this one: https://www.joomshaper.com/joomla-templates/helix3

Answer (score 0):

Using Joomla 4, but I think it's the same in Joomla 3, you can read the headers, add to them, then write them back.  You could do this in your template's index.php quite close to the top. The code would, for example, look like:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
# get the headers
$head_data = $doc->getHeadData();
# twitter
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:card"] = "summary_large_image";
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:title"] = $head_data["title"];
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:description"] = $head_data["description"];
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:site"] = "@StreetArtAberde";
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:creator"] = "@AndyGasman";
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:image"] = Uri::root() . "images/my_image_for_twitter_card.jpg";
# open graph / facebook
$head_data["metaTags"]["property"]["og:title"] = $head_data["title"];
$head_data["metaTags"]["property"]["og:description"] = $head_data["description"];
$head_data["metaTags"]["property"]["og:url"] = $url;
$head_data["metaTags"]["property"]["og:image"] = Uri::root() . "images/metadata_images/street_art_aberdeen_map.jpg";
$head_data["metaTags"]["property"]["og:type"] = "website";
# set it back
$doc->setHeadData($head_data);
```

This would add social metadata to tags, like...

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Map - Street Art Aberdeen">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Street Art Aberdeen is a collaborative visual guide to street art in the city of Aberdeen, Scotland">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@StreetArtAberde">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@AndyGasman">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://streetartaberdeen.org/images/metadata_images/street_art_aberdeen_map.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="Map - Street Art Aberdeen">
<meta property="og:description" content="Street Art Aberdeen is a collaborative visual guide to street art in the city of Aberdeen, Scotland">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://streetartaberdeen.org/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://streetartaberdeen.org/images/metadata_images/street_art_aberdeen_map.jpg">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
```