# How to edit the Joomla template header?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

Basically, I am just trying to slightly modify my Joomla template.

There is a line of code within the `<head>` of my template that is obviously grabbing things such as meta description, meta keywords and title tags.

Here is the code `<jdoc:include type="head" />`

I would like to know where this code is located since I would like my `title tag` above both my `meta description` and `meta keywords`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/43669543/1226309 Regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

Its not recommended editing core files.

You can find the meta and title section of the Joomla sites.

```
libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php
```

contains a function `fetchHead()`

Hope its helped...

Comment: If I could up-vote your answer 1000 times over I would. Worked perfectly and was exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It did help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the header.php to your template folder (name it head_renderer.php) and inside the index.php from your template reference the new header.php via:

> require_once dirname(**FILE**) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
>   'head_renderer.php'; // our modifized renderer for the Joomla header

then you do not fully "edit the core files". However its a hack and not a template overwrite. But via this approach you can update joomla and do not need to check if your changed header.php is changed.

A better howto can be found [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/joomla/36-customize-the-jdoc-include-type-head-part.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the header values with...

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$head_data = $doc->getHeadData();
```

...then set new values, or update the existing values with code like...

```
$head_data["metaTags"]["name"]["twitter:title"] = $head_data["title"];
```

...then write it back with...

```
$doc->setHeadData($head_data);
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410700/789137